# Can I delete old snap folders which used to be installed but remain on system?

Tags: 18.04, snap

If I look in /home/username/snap I have some folders for previously installed and uninstalled programs.

Am I safe to delete these folders, is there a cleaner or auto way of doing this when snaps are uninstalled?

If I run the command snap list or snap list -all they aren't shown.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: Updated my answer for you. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the folders are empty. If they are it's safe to remove them.

If they aren't empty, check file properties for some of them and look at when they were last accessed. This should tell you if those files have been in use recently by any other software. Should be safe to remove those folders if they haven't been accessed recently.

Using your file manager (dolphin, on my system) you can right click on the file, then select `Properties`. Look for `Accessed`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: They all just contain 1 file named 'current'. If I try to open that file it says move to trash as the link is broken?!

Comment: If you've already uninstalled the software, there shouldn't be anything accessing those files since you uninstalled it.